# What is reliable way to start external program for c# application

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

From my C# application I want to start another application that requires admin privilleges and has manifest that ensures it.
My part of code:

```
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"MyLauncher.exe");
                startInfo.Arguments = "/a"; 
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;  
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Current.Shutdown();
```

Unfortunatelly sometimes application start smoothly but from time to time only UAC dialog appears but the application does not start. 
I tried different startup settings but no luck.

Comment: Ensure that this application runs with administrator privileges to begin with, then it should be able to open the other application with the equivalent privileges.

Comment: is the calling process itself always elevated?

Comment: The process method in C# is just as reliable as starting an application from a shortcut.  Try starting program from a shortcut and see if same results occur.

Comment: The chronic problem is assuming that it has something to do with your code but it is actually the program you start that immediately bombs.  Albeit that not setting the startInfo.WorkingDirectory is a pretty good way to trigger a bug.  Use p.WaitForExit() and then look at p.ExitCode and you'll know a little bit more.

Comment: "but from time to time only UAC dialog appears but the application does not start" -- Are you saying that the app isn't starting because there's a UAC prompt there, and you want the app to start programmatically even when there is no human there to click "yes" on the UAC prompt?

Comment: @Quantic. UAC Dialog appears, user clicks yes and that is all. It looks like that the program does not work on. But this is not a rule, sometimes the program works correctly.

Comment: When the UAC dialog appears, then the invoking code will already be past the `Process.Start` call, and it is out of its hands. If you have the source of the called assembly, add diagnostics there. Also look into the security event log.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242800/debugging-code-after-process-start-in-visual-studio